# How to turn a 2D char array into char**

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am creating a software that needs to be able to start a program, for this, it creates an `argv` for the new program. This `argv` is not a `char **` but a 2d `char` array (`char [x][y]`) and causes error 14 in posix_spawn.
But when I tried just passing its own `argv`, it worked fine. So, how do I turn a `char[][]` into a `char **` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc()` to allocate the array, then copy the pointers to each element into it.

```
char **new_argv = malloc(x * sizeof *new_argv);
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    new_argv[i] = argv[i];
}
```

Comment: This is working pretty well, but there is trailing garbage data in the argv appearently, because when its set to run `/usr/bin/echo`with the arguments `testy testy test`, but the output is `testy testy test    �C�   �� �V  � P  �~|F�   0|F�     �` and its seemingly random every time.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't set `x` correctly. It should be the same as `argc`.

Comment: my error was that only the first 4 elements of the `argv` array were actually defined. i fixed this by just setting the remaining elements to `""`, so that way they are defined and not just garbled data.

Comment: That will work OK for `echo`, but it's not a good general solution.